# How do you derive the Rayleigh Roughness Criterion

Tags: electromagnetism, scattering, coherence

In many textbooks and papers discussing electromagnetic scattering from rough surfaces, the Rayleigh Roughness Criterion is defined as:

$h < \frac{\lambda}{8\cos\theta}$ (1)

In (1), $h$ is the difference in height between two specularly reflected rays, $\lambda$ is the wavelength of incident light, and $\theta$ is the incidence angle. This follows from the definition of the phase difference, $\Delta\phi$, between rays specularly reflected at different heights:

$\Delta\phi = 2kh\cos\theta$ (2)

In (2) $k$ is the wavenumber, $k=2\pi/\lambda$. The Rayleigh Roughness Criterion, (1) can be obtained from (2) by limiting $\Delta\phi < \pi/2$ and rearranging for $h$. Below is a figure illustrating the geometry of the problem between a ray, A, reflected at height $h$ and ray, B, reflected at some reference surface:

[image]

If $h=0$, ray A reflects from the same reference surface as ray B and the rays are coherent. The phase difference in (2) arises from the physical distance $h\cos\theta$, which according to the geometry in the above figure corresponds with distance $a$. The right-angle triangle used to define $a$ comes from a line parallel to ray A, the distance $h$, and a line perpendicular to ray A.

My question is, why does the phase difference not arise from the distance $d$ in the above figure? That is what I intuitively would expect, and corresponds with many figures I've seen describing the Rayleigh Roughness Criterion.

In the general case of non-specular reflection, where the scattered angle does not equal the incidence angle, I found the following description in the MIT OpenCourse "Acoustical Oceanography" Lecture 12 (https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-682-acoustical-oceanography-spring-2012/):

[image]

I've tried to break down the geometry in this general case, but won't include that figure here since it's very convoluted. The $(h_{1} - h_{2})(\cos\theta_{1} + \cos\theta_{2})$ terms are analagous to the distance $a$ in the first figure for the incident ray and scattered ray (in the first figure both are equal since $\theta_{1} = \theta_{2}$, which explains the factor of 2 in equation (2)). I can't really make sense of the $\sin$ terms.

Can someone please explain how to properly derive the phase difference in equation (2), and the more general phase difference given by:

$\Delta\phi = k[(h_{1} - h_{2})(\cos\theta_{1} + \cos\theta_{2}) + (x_{2} - x_{1})(\sin\theta_{1} - \sin\theta_{2})]$

This has been really bugging me, since I think that I'm just overlooking something simple. Thanks!

Comment: $d = \frac{\cos\theta} h $ (from the figure) has a dimensional problem. (Also: phase is a scalar, so it should come from a $\vec k \cdot \vec r$).

Comment: @JEB I noticed the $d = \frac{\cos\theta}{h}$ problem just after posting, it should be $d = \frac{h}{\cos\theta}$. I think the dot product you mention is what I'm missing: in vector notation $\vec{h} \dot \vec{d} = \vec{a}$. Can you explain in a little more detail how you calculate the phase difference?